# A CORS POST request works from plain JavaScript, but why not with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm trying to make a Cross Origin post request, and I got it working in plain `JavaScript` like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = "action=something";
request.open('POST', url, true);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {if (request.readyState==4) alert("It worked!");};
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
request.send(params);
```

But I would like to use `jQuery`, but I can't get it to work. This is what I'm trying:

```
$.ajax(url, {
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{action:"something"}, 
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {alert("success");},
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert("failure");}
});
```

This results in Failure. If anyone knows why `jQuery` doesn't work, please let us all know. Thanks.

(I'm using `jQuery` 1.5.1, and Firefox 4.0, and my server is responding with a proper `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header)

Comment: This was the solution for me (use Javascript's XMLHttpRequest) while facing CORS issues with Ionic framework 3.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

UPDATE: As TimK pointed out, this isn't needed with jquery 1.5.2 any more. But if you want to add custom headers or allow the use of credentials (username, password, or cookies, etc), read on.

---

I think I found the answer! (4 hours and a lot of cursing later)

```
//This does not work!!
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

You need to manually specify all the headers you will accept (at least that was the case for me in FF 4.0 & Chrome 10.0.648.204).

jQuery's $.ajax method sends the "x-requested-with" header for all cross domain requests (i think its only cross domain).

So the missing header needed to respond to the OPTIONS request is:

```
//no longer needed as of jquery 1.5.2
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
```

If you are passing any non "simple" headers, you will need to include them in your list (i send one more):

```
//only need part of this for my custom header
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, x-requested-by
```

So to put it all together, here is my PHP:

```
// * wont work in FF w/ Allow-Credentials
//if you dont need Allow-Credentials, * seems to work
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com');
//if you need cookies or login etc
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
if ($this->getRequestMethod() == 'OPTIONS')
{
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 604800');
  //if you need special headers
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with');
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Note that jQuery 1.5.2 has changed its behaviour.  It no longer adds a "X-Requested-With" header, so this might no longer be an issue. http://blog.jquery.com/2011/03/31/jquery-152-released/ (Bug 8423)

Comment: @TimK, you are right! I did not notice they release 1.5.2.

That being said, this also works if you need it to be pre-flighted. I've updated my answer.

Comment: So, I'm confused. You ended up having to write an intermediate PHP script anyway? So you don't need to worry about using Ajax then, right? Or am I missing something.  Is there no JavaScript only solution?

Comment: @Elisabeth This method only works if you control the requested destination...it is NOT an intermediate script. It is the top of our PHP of our requested location. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes! thanks Will. I thought you could control everything from the client side, but it sounds like you need control of both ends.

Comment: I can confirm that jQuery 1.6 does not send any X- headers but that the preflight is still triggered - apparently because of the Content-Type request header - and which fails on any servers (like CouchDB) which don't implement the OPTIONS method.

Comment: is this header above a property of $.ajax()?

Answer (score 19):

Another possibility is that setting `dataType: json` causes JQuery to send the `Content-Type: application/json` header.  This is considered a non-standard header by CORS, and requires a CORS preflight request.  So a few things to try:

1) Try configuring your server to send the proper preflight responses.  This will be in the form of additional headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

2) Drop the `dataType: json` setting.  JQuery should request `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default, but just to be sure, you can replace `dataType: json` with `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I tried not setting dataType, and setting it to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and even `text/plain`.  And I tried adding a response header of `Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"` Nothing worked.

Comment: Can you look in the JavaScript error console (or Firebug's console) and see if there are any errors during the request?  Also, if you know how to use Wireshark, you can use that to see the actual HTTP requests going over the wire.

Comment: "Another possibility is that setting dataType: json causes JQuery to send the Content-Type: application/json header" — This does not happen. `dataType` influences the `Accept` request header but not the `Content-Type` request header.

Answer (score 9):

You are sending "params" in js:
`request.send(params);`

but "data" in jquery". Is data defined?:
  `data:data,`

Also, you have an error in the URL:

```
$.ajax( {url:url,
         type:"POST",
         dataType:"json",
         data:data, 
         success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {alert("success");},
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert("failure");}
});
```

You are mixing the syntax with the one for $.post

---

**Update**: I was googling around based on monsur answer, and I found that you need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` (below is the full paragraph)

http://metajack.im/2010/01/19/crossdomain-ajax-for-xmpp-http-binding-made-easy/

> How CORS Works
>
> CORS works very similarly to Flash's
>   crossdomain.xml file. Basically, the
>   browser will send a cross-domain
>   request to a service, setting the HTTP
>   header Origin to the requesting
>   server. The service includes a few
>   headers like
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin to
>   indicate whether such a request is
>   allowed.
>
> For the BOSH connection managers, it
>   is enough to specify that all origins
>   are allowed, by setting the value of
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *. The
>   Content-Type header must also be
>   white-listed in the
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers header.
>
> Finally, for certain types of
>   requests, including BOSH connection
>   manager requests, the permissions
>   check will be pre-flighted. The
>   browser will do an OPTIONS request and
>   expect to get back some HTTP headers
>   that indicate which origins are
>   allowed, which methods are allowed,
>   and how long this authorization will
>   last. For example, here is what the
>   Punjab and ejabberd patches I did
>   return for OPTIONS:
>
> ```
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type 
> Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
> ```

Comment: Sorry. Yes. `var data = {action:"something"}`

Comment: You can compare the syntax for both functions here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I just tried it with the url in the settings, but same problem.  The .ajax function can take it either way.

Comment: I already had two of those headers.  I added the other two.  Still "failure" with jQuery.  The plain javascript still works.

Comment: The last thing I can think of is to use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup to set `jQuery.ajaxSetup({'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader(string, string)}})` and play with the different headers sent (an example for rails here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Cors change the request method before it's done, from POST to OPTIONS, so,  your post data will not be sent.
The way that worked to handle this cors issue, is performing the request with ajax, which does not support the OPTIONS method.
example code:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            crossdomain: true,
            url: "http://localhost:1415/anything",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                anydata1: "any1",
                anydata2: "any2",
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result)
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(xhr, status, err);
            }
        });
```

---

with this headers on c# server:

```
                    if (request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                    {
                          response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
                          response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                          response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                    }
                    response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Answer (score -2):

Modify your Jquery in following way:

```
$.ajax({
            url: someurl,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSONObject,
            headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }, //add this line
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',                
            success: function (Data) {....}
});
```

Comment: Why would I want to make my Ajax callas synchronous!?

Comment: `contentType: 'application/json', data: JSONObject,` — The server isn't expecting JSON, so sending JSON wouldn't make sense. Also [There is no such thing as a JSON Object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: `headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }, //add this line` — **Never** do that. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header, not a request header. At best this will do nothing. At worst it will convert the request from a simple request to a preflighted request which makes it evern harder to deal with on the server.