# Cross Domain Authentication via Ajax (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cross-domain

There are a lot of similar questions asked, though I didn't really find a good answer. Here is the scenario.

### Given:

Three websites with different domain names (not just different subdomains):

- *Site 1*: Domain: **CrossDomainServer.com** - I have full control over this website. Server side technology - asp.net-mvc
- *Site 2*: Domain: **CrossDomainClient.com** - I can only ask their admin to put some javascript/html on their page.
- *Site 3*: Domain: **CrossDomainEvil.com** - A website that does not have permissions to use services provided by CrossDomainServer.com

### Goals:

- When CrossDomainClient.com loads their page with the javascript provided by CrossDomainServer.com, there needs to be a check whether CrossDomainClient.com is allowed to use services. If it does, display these services, if it does not - display a login form.
- Once logged in, this site should not be asked to login again when they reload the page.
- Once logged in CrossDomainClient.com should be able to GET and POST data to CrossDomainServer.com via ajax.

  - Noah gives a good [article reference](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) to solve this requirement.
  - Also here is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405459/how-to-do-ajax-post-cross-domain-with-custom-headers/14739573#14739573) on how to implement this in asp.net-mvc.
- If CrossDomainEvil.com places the same script on their page, they should not be allowed to use services when user is authorized on CrossDomainClient.com - they should see a login form.

---

It seems that [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) is **not** what I'm looking for since it allows single point of entry into *multipple* systems.

It would be best if someone could point me to the article "for dummies" on how to achieve that since I really don't even know where to begin.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to use cross origin resource sharing (CORS) to allow for cross domain AJAX POST requests.  HTML5 Rocks has a good article to get you started with it: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/.  I don't know asp.net-mvc, so I can't help with the actual authentication logic.

Comment: I should have probably mentioned this, but I already looked into CORS.  Indeed it solves cross domain GET and POST ajax requests requrement. The most help I need with the authentication itself. Though the article is great! Thanks for that!