# Getting elements from JSON into html with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using following code to get some elements out of this JSON, but nothing seems to work. Anybody has an idea of what I'm doing wrong? (I've spent a long time trying to figure it out).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON('http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=Stockholm&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=e8536d3a52101433121710', function(Wdata) {
                $.each(Wdata.data, function() {

                $('<div id="test"></div>').append(

                        this.weather[0].date;

                        ).appendTo('body');

                  });
    });
});
```

my HTML looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="se">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Title of This Web Page</title>
        <script src="scripts\jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts\js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
              <div id="test">
              </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{

    "data": {
        "current_condition": [ … ],
        "request": [ … ],
        "weather": [
            {
                "date": "2012-10-17",
                "precipMM": "0.8",
                "tempMaxC": "11",
                "tempMaxF": "51",
                "tempMinC": "8",
                "tempMinF": "46",
                "weatherCode": "119",
                "weatherDesc": [
                    {
                        "value": "Cloudy"
                    }
                ],
                "weatherIconUrl": [
                    {
                        "value": "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0003_white_cloud.png"
                    }
                ],
                "winddir16Point": "SW",
                "winddirDegree": "224",
                "winddirection": "SW",
                "windspeedKmph": "27",
                "windspeedMiles": "17"
            },
            { … }
        ]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript console. Read the errors it gives you.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Terminate statements, not expressions. Remove the `;` from `this.weather[0].date;`

If you fix that then you get:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=Stockholm&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=e8536d3a52101433121710. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Which is [well covered on this site](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Access-Control-Allow-Origin&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Access-Control-Allow-Origin&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: You open the JavaScript console in your browser. In Chrome it is under Tools>Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

If your request os a cross domain = the url is not from your domain you should set the cross domain flag or use jsonp instead.

Comment: How do I set the cross domain flag?

Comment: read this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working

Comment: This is a tiny plugin that will help you do it
https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/