# CrossDomain ajax request using CORS

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I am trying to POST to my **cross domain** **Rest service** via javascript, and realized that's not possible unless I use this specfication;

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled

But there is very limited documentation how I can implement this, I have a few questions;

1- I use **Glassfish Jee6** app server so can I simply add a **jetty** filter to my web.xml and job is done?

2- And for client side(mobile website), is there any javascript library which helps to implement this specification? Can I still use the existing ajax functions in JQuery  or I need something more specific?

Comment: why dont you make a server side proxy, have your client code query the proxy and get the results back?

Comment: @3nigma I thought about it but 1- I read that it eats up resources-both processing power, bandwidth. 2- I have no clue how can I do that :)

Comment: for jetty there is a cross origin filter or you can just add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: * and for jQuery you can do jsonp and do jQuery.support.cors = true; for opera etc

Comment: @Karussell isnt jsonp for only GET? I need POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty filter:

```
<web-app>
 <filter>
   <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
       <param-value>*</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
       <param-value>*</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
       <param-value>*</param-value>
   </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
     <filter-pattern>*</filter-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: tnx do I ALSO have to add Access-Control-Allow-Headers in the code? or this is eneough?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working do you think answer given to this comforms to this filter situation?

Comment: The filter config I gave you allows all headers and all methods from all origins.