# ajax POST request returns failure

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The following script returns a failure, even though it used to work:

```
function postToPHP(data_to_send) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        async: false,
        url: "http://school.edu/myurl/write_to_mongo.php",
        data: data_to_send,
        success: function ($msg) {
            alert('success');
            return;
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('failure to send to database');
        }
    });
```

In case it matters, it interacts with the following PHP script:

```
//Get data from .ajax call
$data = $_POST;

//Open mongo and select database
$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->selectDB("numbers");

//select a collection
$collection = $db->testData;

//insert data
$collection->insert($data);

//find collection contents
$cursor = $collection->find();

echo $data;
?>
```

Any idea what's gone wrong? My Safari debugger is showing me "failure to load resource. There was a bad response from server.", but hunting this down on Google isn't producing anything useful; I've already made sure I'm importing jQuery properly.

Comment: Why pass `$msg` if it's not inside your `success: function`?

Comment: For debugging purposes, swap async: false, to true and see if the error message is any better. Are you calling a different domain or sub domain? What does the network tab show?

Comment: Changing async: false to true produces no message; neither a failure one nor a success one.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot find server at `http://school.edu/myurl/write_to_mongo.php` when put url into address bar. Plus they would have to allow CORS. Therefore, if they do allow CORS then the Server is down, otherwise it's a Same Origin Policy issue.

Comment: Yes, that url doesn't exist; I just didn't want to post the url publicly. Thank you, though.

Comment: In either case, all of my files are in the same location; the request is being made at the same location as the .php file. Am I missing something?

Comment: If your files are in the same location, use a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Same_origin_policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

AJAX can only communicate within same domain url.

---

Check if page url is not found .

```
function postToPHP(data_to_send) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "jsonp", //for crossDomain request
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true, //crossDomain request
        url: "http://school.edu/myurl/write_to_mongo.php",
        data: data_to_send,
        success: function ($msg) {
            alert('success');
            return;
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('failure to send to database');
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function () { // if page is not found
                alert("page not found");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

---

[How to get a cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) post request working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working)

[What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Comment: Not if CORS is allowed.

Comment: Also, if JSONP or SCRIPT data type is requested, SOP does not apply. Worth noting, maybe :)

Comment: The .js file that contains the AJAX request is in the same domain as the .php file it's trying to communicate with.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing the issue by having the url in the .ajax request be local, e.g.:

```
url: "write_to_mongo.php"
```

For whatever reason, giving a full url caused it to be treated as originating from a different domain even though it wasn't.