# $.post not triggering function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really don't get why `alert` or `console.log` is not being triggered in this code:

```
            $.post("http://localhost:8080/mail",
                     jsonObject,
                     function(data) {
                    console.log("Done!");
                       alert("Thank you for your inquiry. We will get back to you soon.");
                       alert("Response: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                     }
                  );
```

While I can see the mail API works as I was able to get the email with the values I put in the HTML forms. `alert` and `console.log` is not being triggered what could be the reason?

I can see this on the browser log though:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at `http://localhost:8080/mail`. This can be fixed
>   by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Could this be the reason? If so what should I do to make `$.post` trigger success or failure.

Comment: Yes that's the reason. *"If so what should I do to make $.post trigger success or failure."* As the message says: "This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

Comment: you have a CORS problem. basically that means that you will need to change your backend implementation to return the correct headers. you can refer to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working)

Comment: if chrome, open from the command line with: `chromium-browser --disable-web-security`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross Origin Requests (CORS) is your issue. `$.ajax()` crossDomain parameter as documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/mail",
    crossDomain : true,
    data: jsonObject
    ...
})
```

Regarding how to catch a success or failure: You can chain [done(), fail(), and always()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR) to   `$.post`

```
$.post("http://localhost:8080/mail", jsonObject, function(data) {
    // alert("success");
}).done(function(){
    // alert("success 2");
}).fail(function() {
    // alert( "error" );
}).always(function(){
   //  alert( "finished" );
});
```

Which also works with `$.ajax()` or use callbacks within `$.ajax()`

```
$.ajax(function(){
    success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {},
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
});
```