# Node CORS package not working

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, cors

I've inserted the following lines into my code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();

app.options('*', cors());
app.use(cors());
```

However, when I make an AJAX POST request, I still get the error:

```
POST https://stormy-plateau-94715.herokuapp.com/login 
new-page-5:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://stormy-plateau-94715.herokuapp.com/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://squareguru.squarespace.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

This is my first time using the cors package, am I configuring something wrong? I would love any help you guys can give me, thanks!

Comment: Is stormy-plateau-94715 your app or someone else's

Comment: It's my app. It's one of the free hobby dynos on Heroku.

Comment: Try adding this code to the top of your login endpoint: `res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");`

Comment: I added the following code: 
`app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,GET,POST');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});`

I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Maybe try changing that to have a star instead of empty string here: `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` If it still doesn't work. Try moving that code directly into the post function to see if your `app.all` isn't working. Edit: I see that there is a star there now.

Comment: You also might need `crossdomain:true` in your ajax post. Can you post your ajax code? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923796/cors-error-with-jquery

Comment: I guess you don't need `app.options('*', cors());` just `app.use(cors());`

Comment: Also, your app appears to be crashed

Comment: Haha that's embarrassing. Okay, moving all of those headers into my app.post('/login') function seemed to do the trick. Thanks so much for your help! If you post that as an answer, I can accept it as correct.

Comment: Nah, I'm not going to make an answer because it's not really what you asked. I'm curious why the CORS package didn't fix it for you or why app.all didn't work. Maybe someone will have a better solution.