# JQuery get request callback function not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My code is relatively simple. I have a URL, which is defined before the request is sent, I then have a `$.get()` request, which I expect to return back a JSON object. The code is below.

```
var url = "url"; //Removed for clarity

$.get(url, function (data) {
        alert("hi");
});
```

The url being used within the request is correct. I have copied and pasted the code into my browser and I receive the response that I expect from the endpoint.

However when this JQuery code is executed, the callback function is not called and the alert is not fired. Why is this happening?

Edit: Forgot to post the error message I found in the console.

I'm receiving this:

```
2Initial%20Loan#:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'-snip url-' from 
origin 'https://localhost:44358' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Will it have anything to do with the GET request not working?

Comment: Check the console for errors in the request. The callback of `$.get` only works when the request is successful (ie. a 200/204 response is received)

Comment: Check the console and post more meaningful error message

Comment: copy the URL and run in Browser new tab. Chances are it will fail or return an error, In that case, your callback block will not work.

Comment: @MyTwoCents Did you read the OP? That's exactly what I have done. It returns a correct 200 with JSON data.

Comment: @NirbhayJha I have updated the OP with an error message I am getting from my browser console.

Comment: Its CORS issue.  API which you are trying to call doesn't support CORS.

Comment: It's CORS issue, try this chrome plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problem with the url. The syntax specified by you is correct and the same is checked

```
var url = "https://jsfiddle.net/"; //Removed for clarity

$.get(url, function (data) {
    alert("hi");
});
```

[working code](https://jsfiddle.net/67gytdcr/)

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, the URL is correct and returns a 200 and JSON data.

Comment: as per your OP, the server from which you are requesting data does not allow request for another server. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923796/cors-error-with-jquery for more info

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of CORS, which stands for Cross origin resource sharing. Browsers prevent sending AJAX request to domain other than where the javascript file originated from.

As the error message says you have to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' http response header from your server code. Read more about CORS here [enter link description here [CORS MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)