# how to add header while posting a url and raw data in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have to pass header information while posting a url and want to pass raw data in the url can any on help me on this

i have tried

```
function test(){
    alert("test");
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("X-APIKEY", "y5q9q1at8u-1uf4bao2yq-bsjdj3gh1g-u9ymh1t2f8-tt85pn4r50");
            },
            url: "https://backoffice.hostcontrol.com/api/v1/domain-is",
            data: {"domain": "mahrosh.com"},
            processData: false,
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
                $("#results").append("The result =" + StringifyPretty(msg));
            }
    });
}
```

its not returning me results

Comment: it generates a Cross-origin error

Comment: what is cross origin error

Comment: Cross domain request are forbidden with AJAX, you need to find a workaround.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working

Answer (score 0):

You can add header variables as per given in below described code

```
function test(){
alert("test");
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    headers: { 'X-APIKEY': 'y5q9q1at8u-1uf4bao2yq-bsjdj3gh1g-u9ymh1t2f8-tt85pn4r50'},
    url: "https://backoffice.hostcontrol.com/api/v1/domain-is",
    data: {"domain": "mahrosh.com"},
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
}
```

If server gives error in response than you have idea about it so i added the error section as well ...

Comment: it is returning nothing no reply no text

Comment: @Salman the response I got is {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: @Salman Please take anote that I got this message also in the console .. XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://backoffice.hostcontrol.com/api/v1/domain-is. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Salman so it might be the issue of localhost .. are you doing the same  means accessing the api through localhost .. ?