# Send apiKey on a html form post or alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing a ASP.NET mvc5 project.
In one of the pages, I have a button that I want to use to do a post to a cross domain api.

I've tried doing the post like this with ajax:

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URLX,
        data: myJSObject,

        success: function (data) {
            console.log("test123");
        },
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            //"Authorization": "Bearer XX+n06LhXHb/cAZyBSvXZAd1LlkO8NqtORuHGyexWr4=",
            "apiKey": "MEV8yv3hxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFdKWJer4H3LmL6ntcL",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }

    });
```

but from what I read I can't do a cross domain request with JavaScript, so I tried with a form:

```
<div class="hiddenform">
<iframe name="hiddenFrame" width="0" height="0" border="0" style="display: none;"></iframe>
<form action="http//something.com/otherthing" id="login_form" method="post" target="hiddenFrame">
    <div class="form_section">You can login here</div>
    <div class="form_section">
        <input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="text" id="userIdform"
               name="session[sec1]" tabindex="1" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form_section">
        <input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="text" id="periodform"
               name="session[sec2]" tabindex="1" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form_section">
        <input xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="text" id="benchform"
               name="session[sec3]" tabindex="1" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form_section">etc</div>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="buttons">
        <button type="submit" class="" name="" id="goform" tabindex="3">Go</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

also, this is the server CORS config https://gist.github.com/michiel/1064640

My problem is that I need to send a header with a apiKey, is that possible in a form? If not, what other options are there that allow me to do a cross domain post when I press a button on my asp.net MVC5 page?

Thanks

Comment: you can pass the api key in hidden field using <input type='hidden' />

Comment: @Amit, it will not work if `endpoint` requires header to be present.

Comment: it requires apiKey yes, its mandatory

Answer (score 1):

You **can do** cross-domain `XMLHttpRequest` using [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working) if your endpoint support it.

These headers are **response** headers and they are returned from server if CORS is enabled. You should not send them to server.

```
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
```

So, just make sure that your server returns `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

You should only send your custom header (with API key) that way (you're on right way):

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    headers: { 'APIKeyPost': 'MEVxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4H3LmL6ntcL' }
    ...
});
```

Comment: yes, i edited my post with the more updated ajax that i used, first one was a older version. The request reaches the server as "Options" instead of post, and in their config they have this: https://gist.github.com/michiel/1064640  , hence im getting a HTTP/1.1 204 No Content response

Comment: Remove `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your request and make sure that these headers are returned from your endpoint.

Comment: Are you sure that request is handled as `OPTIONS` request? Check your browser's Network tab to see activity for XHR requests.

Comment: if i dont use the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Headers headers i get POST https://.../bench/book 500 (Internal Server Error) and this is what appears in browser network http://paste2.org/0ZIY5OIM