# Call asmx service from cross domain

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to call ASMX service from my another domain. So far I have the following code of sample:

```
e.preventDefault();
var CityName = {};
CityName.Name = $("input#name").val();
$.ajax({
    data: '{name:' + JSON.stringify($("input#name").val()) + '}',
    url: 'http://192.168.1.110/forgetit//webservice.asmx/CityTestExample',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:
        function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            alert("data Saved");
        } 
    });
});
```

basically from one domain i wants to insert data that is call asmx service from another domain how should i get this my web console give me this error

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   please give me any suggestion it will be very helpful for me thanks.

Comment: If you control the service that you're calling then you need to add CORS headers to the responses. How you do that is an issue for the service, not jQuery.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how should i do this can you give me any sample code thanks

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes i have control of the service thanks

Comment: you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working

Comment: I don't know as I've never worked with an ASMX service. I'm sure if you google 'ASMX CORS headers' you should have plenty of references to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain hosting Web service should enable the cross domain policy. There are many ways to enable this. Please see the MSDN link for more details.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470115(VS.95).aspx