# Cross Domain call using WCF

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf

I have hosted WCF service to cloud & if I POST ajax call then it's behaving properly.

[image]

Where as when I am posting it from other web page then I am getting OPTIONS HTTP.

[image]

Now if I go to the IE browser & enable the Access data sources across domain then it's working properly.

[image]

I made some changes go my WCF service as well like:
Added global.asax class file & POST header is case it's get OPTIONS:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
  HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            processData:false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: null,
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data.LeadCreated);
            }
        });
```

Comment: try "jsonp" instead of "json" dataType.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working

Comment: Try [WCFBehaviorExtension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebHttpBehaviorExtensions). See instructions [here](https://github.com/cshandler/WebHttpBehaviorExtensions) how to setup the Cors in few steps.