# Angular $http is not sending data

Tags: angularjs, http, http-post, asp.net-web-api2

I know it has been solved here many times, but I'm still not able to get it working.

My js call is:

```
var data = { value: 7 };
$http.post('api/controller/method', data);
```

But in fiddler there is no Content-Type and no JSON data.
I want the Content-Type to be 'application/json' which should be default, right?

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bkUEu/458/

Comment: Still not working. It's sending OPTIONS verb instead POST (posting against WebApi2). When I compose a POST in fiddler, it is working though

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do a cross-domain POST. The browser will send OPTIONS if you are doing a cross-domain request.

Comment: Yes, I'm. And it is allowed on the server.

Comment: Is the server responding to `OPTIONS`? The server should return `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST`.

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = { value: 7 };
$http({
        url: "api/controller/method",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: $.param(data)
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //some code when success post
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //some code when error post
        });
```

Comment: Helped, thanks. But why the urlencoded is working instead of applicaion/json?

Comment: And it will not work when the simple value like 7 will be sent.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data) answer your cuestion about the **urlencoded** @matt-bridges

Comment: And why wil not work with the simple value?, You have to check in the back end what parameters you are receiving and give an response

Comment: When I send just 7, I read 0 on server. When I wrap it into var post = { data: 7 }, I have the object with property data = 7 on the server. Simple value does not work to me..  
I have solved it with generics on the server side, but I don't get it why..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var response = $http.post('api/controller/method', data);
response.success(function(data, status1, headers, config) {
    //
}
```