# Live Update Get Request

Tags: javascript, php, html, http, get

Using javascript / another client side scripting language I need to show the result of a http get request, and update every X seconds without refreshing. The api I am working with is external and works like this:
You send it a request, no parameters, and it returns a number. I need to display this in a static html site and live update it every 2 seconds.

So far I have been able to live update using functions like `Math.random()` and setInterval but my trouble is making a GET request inside the JavaScript, to an external domain. I have a working php script that provides the result but I do not know how to integrate this into the JS

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post effort and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly advice to call the function again inside the success of the api call. A solution using setInterval may hammer the site even when it gives errors. Also the request can take longer than 2 second to execute

Here I use jQuery for simplicity's sake

Use setTimeout inside the success:

```
function getIt() { 
  $.get("url",function(data) { 
    $("#container").text(data); 
    setTimeout(getIt,2000);
  });
}
getIt();
```

If the URL is crossdomain, you may want to look into JSON and CORS:
[How to get a cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) post request working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working)

Comment: So would this work if "url" was an external domain?

Comment: If the url allows it - i.e. has set up CORS to allow you to access it or allows JSONP

Answer (score -1):

Just use Ajax and setInterval():

```
setInterval(function(){ 

//your Ajax call goes here 

}, 2000);
```

Comment: Never use interval on Ajax.

Comment: @mplungjan what is the reason for not doing as this answer suggests? Why not use Ajax inside interval?

Comment: Because you may hammer the site even when it gives errors. Also the request can take longer than 2 second to execute

Comment: main downfall is the time it takes the get back the response is not determined, so multiple calls could happen before the response ever comes back

Comment: @mplungjan I really only bring up the question of why because it's one thing to say don't do something, but if you have no reason, It's opinion at that point and doesn't give viewers any reason to trust your suggestion.

Comment: @Rasclatt I'll copy the reason to my answer. I did expect to have the discussion in the comment but did not feel I had the time when I posted it

Comment: @mplungjan Great! Now visitors will know why your answer is a better one!