# How do i auto refresh my div class content?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

My code is as follows -

```
<div class="huge">
<?php echo date ("g:i:s A"); ?>
</div>
```

How do i set `<div class="huge">` to refresh every second?

Comment: Could you be more specific, @WebDev.  What is the need for updating it every second..?

Comment: You would need to learn about [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Ajax would not be useful really, unless there is a reason to using it, I'd highly suggest using something like JavaScript to do this.

Comment: @FluxCoder Um, how else would you update a section of a page with Data from the server? If the OP is just updating the time, than yeah, there is no need for the Ajax call.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were just displaying the date.

Comment: PS: if you are using ajax, you may want to think about using `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()` or you may run into ajax requests not completing by the time another is sent:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283721/live-update-get-request/38283741#comment64004522_38283741 The answer by @FluxCoder would be a better choice if Ajax is required, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works too -

```
<script>function getTime(){
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(Date.now());

  return (date.getHours() % 12) + ':' + leadingzero(date.getMinutes()) + ':' + leadingzero(date.getSeconds()) + (date.getHours() < 12 ? ' AM' : ' PM'); ; 
}

function leadingzero(n) {
  return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}

function updateDiv(){
  var d = document.document.getElementsByClassName('yourDivClassname')[0];
  d.innerHTML = getTime();
}

setInterval(updateDiv, 1000);</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you need to get the update from the server (noted the PHP code in your original post), there are two things you need to implement:

1. A Server-Side script (in this case written in PHP) to be requested by the client for fresh data.
2. A Client-Side javascript to fetch fresh data from the server and update your div.

Let's make an example.

**index.php**

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>My date updater</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="huge"><?php echo date ("g:i:s A"); ?></div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

**Javascript (using jQuery)**

```
setInterval(function(){
   $.ajax({
        url:'loadData.php'
   }).done(
        function(data){
            $('.huge').html(data);
   });
},1000);
```

**loadData.php**

```
<?php echo date ("g:i:s A"); ?>
```

Initially your page named in this example *index.php* will load and show the initial date (using a bit of php code inline).

Then the javascript will start to get data from the server (using an ajax request to *loadData.php*) every second and the div will be updated with the fresh data.

Hope it helps a bit!

*P.S: Date and time information can also be fetched using pure javascript code on the client-side, but for some applications the date and time information on the client-side is not reliable enough since it relies on the date and time settings that are set by the client browser.*

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ajax, something like this:

If it's just simple text, or simple HTML being loaded then you could use

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#huge").load("now_playing.php");
    ...
}, 5000);
```

You could also use something like:

```
function reload() { 

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "fetch_message.php",
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $('#huge').innerHTML(data);
        setTimeout(function(){
            reload()
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will update the content of the element with id="huge" every second. you don't need any initial php value.
If you need other elements like minutes and seconds of course you can add dt.getMinutes() and dt.getHours() to the string.

```
<div id="huge"></div>

<script language="javascript">
function refreshSomething(){
var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById('huge').innerHTML = dt.getSeconds();
}


setInterval(function(){
    refreshSomething() // this will run after every second
}, 1000);
</script>
```