# How to fix "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" in jquery file upload?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, cross-domain

I am trying to upload images using file-uploader jquery plugin. But i am getting "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" and not getting any response. Here is one thing my file is place on another server and my ajax url is different

Please check below my code:-

```
var url = 'mysite/upload.php';
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
    alert(data)
    }

});
```

Please update me how this will fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) post request working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working)

Comment: Your URL looks funny. Are you sure the `,php` isn't a typo?

Comment: Read about [CORS](http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/)