# What is a proper way to send parameterized URL and load page into div using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to load page into `<div>` but I'm running out of ideas.
Getting all kind of errors depending of my attempt (mostly
**Cross-Origin Request Blocked**
), so, obviously this is not the way.

this `$("#cmbsHost  option:selected").text()` contains IP, lets say: 139.131.4.5

My last tries:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://ip-api.com/#" + $("#cmbsHost  option:selected").text(),
    crossDomain: true,
    //dataType: "jsonp",
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
```

and of course this one:

```
$("#dlgWhois").load("http://ip-api.com/#" + $("#cmbsHost  option:selected").text());
```

So... how to do it sensei?

Comment: What are you using as your server-side tech?  You can make a call to your own server to make the remote call, which won't be affected by CORS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+cors

Comment: @freedomn-m asp.net, tnx, I'll se what can be done about that

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the full page, and then find the element/text inside the `data` loaded.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://ip-api.com/#"
    crossDomain: true,
    //dataType: "jsonp",
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log( $(data).find("#cmbsHost option:selected").text() );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that url is right with right query string parameter

```html
 $.ajax({
                url: "http://ip-api.com?ip=" + $("#cmbsHost  option:selected").text(),
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data)
                {                    
                    $("#dlgWhois").html(data);
                }
            })
```

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked, usual err