# Rails 5 error XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cors, ruby-on-rails-5

Please helpme.

I use rack_cors gem but not resolved my problem

this is my code

application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'localhost', 'http://example.com'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

this is the error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/video.vtt. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: CORS error have been treated here a lot ; read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working for a start

Comment: Does not solve my problem

Comment: Ok try this. You want to circumvent CORS errors so download google chrome webserver https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en  Once you have it installed it will be helpful.You link your application folder to that "web server" then you run your application from there....Il will help simulate client/server architecture to avoid CORS. Just for testing this may be sufficient (it was for me to test an Ajax application)

Comment: In production I get the same error

Comment: Do you have your front end and back end on different domain ? (if the app running on a domain distinct from the one where the back end program is running ? )

Answer (score 0):

Simply test Rails environment before setting allowed origins.

- Development: '*'
- Production: 'http://example.com'

Comment: Tried with "debug: true" in ruby and development console in browser?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/video.vtt. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: **"Rack::Cors"** instead of **Rack::Cors**?

Comment: Nothing, stays the same :(