# Macy product API jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner programmer trying to form a URL to GET macy product information based on my keyword, here:http://developer.macys.com/docs/read/catalog_and_store_services/catalog/search#requesturl
They have 3 mandatory parameters, 2 of which is in the HTTP header, `Accept` and `x-macys-webservice-client-id` with another being in the query parameter, searchphrase.
[image]
According to the document, I have formed a jQuery function to GET products information:

```
function ajaxsearch(){
    var terms = "reddress";
    var macyurl = "https://api.macys.com/v4/catalog/search?searchphrase="+ terms;
    alert(macyurl);
    var apikey = "6zjre5gv8822t323e6wxj85a";
     $.ajax({
        url: macyurl,
        headers:{
        Accept: application/json,
        x-macys-webservice-client-id: apikey
        }
        success: function(data){
        alert("successful call!") 

        }

    });

}
```

Question: Are the syntax of my function correct? I have checked this with the console and they are having problems with one of the headers, `x-macys-webservice-client-id`. Is this the correctly way to set up HTTP header parameters in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys of an object should follow the same rules of naming a variable. If not, they should be quoted like this:

```
headers:{
    Accept: "application/json", // you can quote the key here too, but the value has to be quoted.
    "x-macys-webservice-client-id": apikey // the key must be quoted since - aren't allowed in key names. if apikey is not a variable, then it should be quoted too.
}, // Plus, you forgot to put a comma here to separate the entries
```

**NOTE**: If you don't know what do `keys` and `values` mean here is what I'm talking about:

```
{
    key: value,
    anotherKey: anotherValue,
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am going to mark this as answer as you have helped me solve my syntax error. Although the request still didn't work probably because macy require cURL from php.

Comment: @Detectivemerry I don't know about Macy. But the errors you had regarding the `headers` object are solved.

Comment: @Detectivemerry I've just tried your code and it shows in the console (in may case) that it's a CORS (cross-origin ressource sharing) error because I'm running it on my localhost. If your error is the same, look how to solve it using that information (CORS). See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working) can help.

Comment: Thank you, again, I will research about this!