# Reading json content from a REST API URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, api

I have built a REST API with Node.js Express http://localhost:3000/api/feeds with node.js and filled with data.

```
router.get('/api/feeds', function (req, res, next) {
    documentDBConfig.getAllDocuments()
        .then(() => res.json(documentDBConfig.feedsArray));
});
```

[image]

Now i make a static website and want to use `javascript` or `jquery` to get data from my REST API. I used this code

```
$.getJSON( "http://localhost:3000/api/feeds", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But it keeps saying

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/feeds. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I know i'm doing it wrong, but i couldn't find the correct way. How can i get this json content with my website from my REST API (http://localhost:3000/api/feeds) ?

Edit: I don't get this warning with explorer, but i can not get the content. And now i solved the chrome problem thus i don't get this warning anymore. But i can't read the content. That is not a duplication.

Now i get this warning

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: @Deividas Karžinauskas yes have read this answers, but am i doing the rest correct? I mean can i read a url content with this jquery function?

Comment: Your jquery function is good. You need to update your server headers to allow requests form other urls. Read the resources suggested by the post.

Comment: @Deividas Karžinauskas but i'm not getting this warning with explorer and i can also not getting the json content too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us your REST api code so we can help you ? You need to set some headers in your backend to allow requests coming from other origins.

If you happen to be using express, this will [help](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html) you. But you could have built the REST api in another way, so please provide us with more information.

Comment: i have added the code app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
}); but nothing has changed

Comment: Thanx Abdel, i got the data in explorer wel in this way. With chrome it doesnt work

Comment: @LeventOner No problem! You were executing the request correctly all along. Next time make sure you do enough googling before you start a question. People dislike questions that have been often answered.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are accessing a resource from another domain.
You try to access http://localhost:3000 from http://localhost:63342.
You can read more about this here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: am i doing the rest correct? I mean can i read a url content with this jquery function?

Comment: Yeah, you are using the proper function.

Comment: but i'm not getting this warning with explorer and i can also not getting the json content too.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are performing a CORS request which means you are trying to call a resource on different server. So your REST api should allow CORS requests by adding the response headers allowing the UI server resource. 
[Please Refer to this question if it helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working)