# How to send OPTIONS Method call to server via ajax jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call an API that accepts OPTIONS method on server, it runs on postman and returns json object but following code is not working on js

I have read that OPTIONS call is a preflight call for CORS calls, so this API is https and on another server. But even then there is no response and it returns 405 method not found

```
 $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            method :"OPTIONS",
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                "Accept": "application/json,long_format",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success" + data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("fail" + data);
            }
        }).fail(function(data) {
            console.log("failed" + data);
            });
```

Extra info :
The API is cross domain and on ssl so to cover cross domain request I had to user `dataType: "jsonp"`

**UPDATED :**

**This is impossible** scenario so I have to get update on server end...

**Explanation:**
There is some problem with
OPTIONS method that is behind cross domain as well
a/c to some research i have done on internet, CORS request can be accessed with :
dataType: "jsonp",
but with -> dataType: "jsonp"
you can only call GET methods
so we are stuck here that allows that either we call cross domain https request or we can call OPTIONS method,
usually OPTIONS method is a preflight method done automatically by browser

**NOW please stop down voting my question**

Comment: Are you trying to make a preflight OPTIONS request or some other OPTIONS request?

Comment: That's a response header, not a request header

Comment: trying to call OPTIONS method

Comment: You probably don't want to make an OPTIONS call manually. The browser should be doing that itself. There are a number of questions on SO about CORS.

Comment: You can't force an ajax request when api is not CORS enabled. Use a proxy

Comment: @AlonEitan you mean If I add 'beforeSend' and add headers there it will hit OPTIONS method ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852011/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-via-ajax)

Comment: @HereticMonkey can you please provide any example code where OPTIONS method is hit on purpose(not preflight)

Comment: Why would I have that example code? I said that the browser should be doing the preflight calls automatically and that you should *not* be making the calls manually.

Comment: @HereticMonkey you mean it can't be made manually? I have called this OPTIONS method from postman and it returns proper result.. There should be some way to call it from ajax too

Comment: You're trying to force a server which does not accept CORS requests to accept a CORS request. Talk to the provider of the service for direction on how to access their service.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> dataType: "jsonp",
> ```

Take this out. JSONP requests **are always** GET requests. This is your main problem.

> ```
> crossDomain: true,
> ```

Take this out. It does nothing unless you are making a *same origin* request that gets **redirected** to be a cross origin request.

> ```
> contentType: 'application/json',
> ```

Take this out. You are making an OPTIONS request. There is no request body to describe the content-type of.

> ```
> "Content-type": "application/json",
> ```

Take this out. For the same reason.

> ```
> "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
> ```

Take this out. It is a **response** header and has no place on the request.

Comment: the request is is cross origin and https method  and without  it 
`dataType: "jsonp` it gives cross origin policy issue

Comment: @ShahrukhAhmad — Then you need to change the server to use CORS to grant you permission to make the request. JSONP can **only** be made with GET requests.

Comment: you mean it can't be made manually? I have called this OPTIONS method from postman and it returns proper result.. There should be some way to call it from ajax too

Comment: Go and read https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068  which explains the point of the same-origin policy.