# Advanced REST Client to jQuery request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, web

I have an ARC set up by the client and everything seems to be working OK in ARC and the back-end, but I cannot see what I'm doing wrong in jQuery

Here's the ARC test

[image]

Here's my jQuery code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  <script>
    let urlBase = 'http://54.210.29.209';
    let urlEnterEmail = '/api/v1/users/checkEmail';

    $(document).ready(function() {

      $.ajax(
        {
          method: "POST",
          crossDomain: true,
          url: urlBase + urlEnterEmail,
          xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
          headers: {
            "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "x-requested-with",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Platform": "web",
            "Build": 2
          },
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {"email": "john@doe.com"}
        }
      )
      .done(function (response) {
        console.log('done!');
        console.log(response);
      })
      .fail(function (xhr, status) {
        console.log('fail!!!');
        //console.log(xhr); 
        console.log(status);
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Finally, the error

[image]

I read a little bit about CORS, but it's not working. The resources I found are the following, and still I don't know if I'm the one with the problem or the back-end code.

[How to get a cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) post request working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working/5753269#5753269)

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: And you're getting no errors, and no response ?

Comment: Try to stringify your data - data: JSON.stringify({ "email": "johndoe@server.com" })

Comment: @Shane noup... not working with stringify :(

Comment: what technology are you using for your backend? Actually the guy who is making the backend has to do something about it - or you could serve your API and frontend over the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

[This example uses AspNet Web Api, C# as Backend]
Your problem seems related to the Api and not to your javascript call itself,
Look at this, it is a Cross Origin call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: CTHelper.ApiUrl() + '/token',
        data: { grant_type: 'password', username: $scope.UserName, password: $scope.Password },
        success: function (result) {
          alert('OK');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
```

but my       API (Back end) allows CORS, this is a part of the file Startup.Auth.cs

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ...
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        ...
    }
```

Microsoft.Owin.Cors can be downloaded as a nuget.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is clearly stated in there. The web browser is restricting your access to the backend due to the lack of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (cross site requests) header from the server.

If your backend is running PHP, using this in the first line of your script should be enough:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    // The rest of your backend script here
    // ...
```

That askerisk (`*`) will basically tell "accept requests from every source". You could, of course, use the same address of the backend if the web page was loaded from it (basically its origin is the same). So if these files are uploaded to your server to the side of the script, this should work too:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://54.210.29.209");
```

I'm not really sure if using `http://localhost` would work, probably not but it's worth trying it.