# send json as data in ajax and get response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, postman

i want to request as json to API and get response and i tried it with postman and i got response:

json request to API:

```
{
"apikey":"&^$%#@!jwebdpqodp9fgkwjebfkdpqihdqlwkndqp"
}
```

response that i got in postman and it is ok

```
{
"status": 200,
"result": {
    "winner": "s",
    "options": {
        "1": "mar",
        "2": "feb",
        "3": "jan",
        "4": "aug"
    },
    "question": "how old are u?",
    "answer": 3
}
```

}

my problem is i want to send ajax request and get response.i try this code but it doesnt get any response?

```
var data = {"apikey":"&^$%#@!jwebdpqodp9fgkwjebfkdpqihdqlwkndqp"};
$.ajax({
type:'post',
dataType:'json',
url:'http://207.154.251.233:8039/app_dev.php/question/get',
data:JSON.stringify(data),
success:(function (response) {
alert(response);
})
})
```

Comment: Add an error handler to find out why

Comment: @charlietfl could you tell me how?

Comment: try removing the quotes from your data around `apikey` so like `{apikey:"&^$%#@!jwebdpqodp9fgkwjebfkdpqihdqlwkndqp"};`

Comment: @Alex.W That makes no sense .... quoting property keys is perfectly valid

Comment: Never mind, you're right!

Comment: @Alex.W nothing changed with that

Comment: *"could you tell me how"* ... by studying  the $.ajax documentation and tutorials

Comment: Maybe you need to add allow-cors=true in header. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working

Answer (score 0):

Use this modified code:

```
var data = {"apikey":"&^$%#@!jwebdpqodp9fgkwjebfkdpqihdqlwkndqp"};
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    url:'http://207.154.251.233:8039/app_dev.php/question/get',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    crossDomain: true,
    data:JSON.stringify(data),
    success:(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    })
});
```

Further if your script runs from different host you must use cross origin access permission. For this, use

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
```

If your application built in php then use:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
// or your script's host, e.g http://foo.example instead of "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting is of type object, and will show up as [object] [object]. You will need to `JSON.stringify` if you want to do an `alert` on it. I suggest using `console.log` instead, it's better for debugging.