# How to integrate MobileFirst Foundation Web SDK to Web Application (Angular5)?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have tried approach mentioned in the [IBM developers works](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/web/) to add the MobileFirst Web SDK. We have created Angular 5 web application and added Web SDK into it. After that, we are not able to figure out where to put MFP server IP or hostname? 
Currently, our web application stays in the different web server and MFP on the different.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy MFP and web application in same web server else their will be a violation of [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Web apps that use the MobileFirst web SDK must be handled in a supporting topology. For example, use a reverse proxy to internally redirect requests to the appropriate server while maintaining the same single origin. More details about Same Origin Policy with respect to Mobilefirst App is [here](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/web/#same-origin-policy).

Once you have supporting topology, Register your web application in MFP Console and update the required properties in `server.js` file of web application.

Please follow this [quick-start tutorial](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/quick-start/web/) for Web end to end demonstration using MFP Platform.

Comment: Thanks @Vittal for a quick response, But as per our architecture we need to have the web application on different web server only. We are not using the Node server. We need to deploy our web application on IIS.

Comment: You will encounter a CORS issue. To overcome it, you can use the CORS extension on the browser or include meta headers in your web app. This has to be done as mentioned in this post : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working

Comment: Please note that using the above headers mentioned could be a security vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a proxy configuration or rules in your webserver , such that it should route the requests to MFP server.