# CORS error while requesting google map api

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I am giving API call to google map API and its throwing cors error.
such as:-
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin

code snippet

```
$.getJSON(
  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" +
    city_lat + "," + city_lon + "&radius=500&type=restaurant&key=AIzaSyC0Lytb6QPHW9NNMwfJva6U4meM9tnvtlk",
  function(val) { }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your Cross Origin Policy.

> Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy.

See this for more information:
[How to get a cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) post request working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

If you are using localhost via Chrome, see this:

> To have Chrome send Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the header, just alias your localhost in your /etc/hosts file to some other domain, like:
>
> 127.0.0.1   localhost yourdomain.com
>
> Then if you'd access your script using yourdomain.com instead of localhost, the call should succeed

Comment: I have used following code but it is also not working:-                                                                                            
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST",
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+city_lat+","+city_lon+"&radius=500&type=restaurant&key=
       );

Comment: Have you adjusted the Cross Origin as described in the links? Without it you can not request rescources from a different server. See this as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS