# CORS error with Validate Shipment Request in Fedex API Integration

Tags: api, fedex

I'm trying to integrate FedEx API in the web applications but I'm getting cors error.
Here is my console error output,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYntj.png)

Can anyone please help to how to resolve this cors error in FedEx API integration?

Here is my code,

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services",
    data: xmlData,
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    cache: false,
    cors: true,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log('result ', result);
    },
    error: function() { 
        console.log('Failed to Validate Shipment Request');
    }
});
```

Comment: `$.ajax({ ..., crossDomain: true, ... })`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) post request working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working)

Answer (score 0):

Add headers in your ajax request

headers: {
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
},

Comment: Yes ,  tried to add header, but still I'm getting cors error

Answer (score -1):

Cross-origin resource sharing is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served.

Please try to install cors package with this command:

```
npm i cors
```

Configuring CORS set as Middleware:

```
 var express = require('express')
 var cors = require('cors')
 var app = express()
 
 var corsOptions = {
   origin: 'http://example.com',
   optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke 
   on 204
 }
```

Comment: He didn't mention that he's using NodeJS. It's just an ajax call, so don't scope down the answer to NodeJS !