# When I call any API is getting a response CORS error for rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cors, rack-cors

I am trying to configure the back-end with the front-end while they are running two different ports. I send a request to it from an app (on a different subdomain than the API) I get the following response:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/products?desc=true&tab=Competition&trending=false&page=1' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

I don't understand why this is happening, since I have already set up `Rack CORS Middleware`.

CROS configuration as follows:

Gemfile:
`gem 'rack-cors'`

config/initializers/cors.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    # TODO: add only authorized url address
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :patch, :put]
  end
end
```

For reference, I have attached a browser error screenshot.
[image]

[image]

Preflight request:
[image]

Preflight response body
[image]

Ajax request :

```
export const fetchProducts = () => (dispatch) => {
  // dispatch(requestProducts())
  const data = { desc: true, tab: 'My Products', trending: false }
  $.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: `http://localhost:3000/api/products?desc=true&tab=Competition&trending=false&page=1`,
    // csrfToken,
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    },
    success(response) {
      console.log(response)
      // dispatch(receiveProducts(response));
    },
    error(xhr) {
      console.log(xhr)
      // dispatch(receiveServerErrors(xhr));
    }
  })
}
```

Thank You

Comment: There should be a "preflight" request of type OPTIONS before the GET - do you see it on the network?

Comment: yes, I have attached a screenshot of that request

Comment: Can you also share how you are doing the ajax request?

Comment: @JoelBlum added in the question

Comment: Can you try adding the request headers like this guy is suggesting? It might be a problem with the ajax request, not rails. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49813910/1032663

Comment: `headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },`
after the added these codes in the request, every time preflight request is generated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244463/discussion-between-santosh-kumbhar-and-joel-blum).

Answer (score 1):

You should try to set the response header key "access-control-allow-credentials" to be true with a specific origin. Like the code below:

```
# config/initializers/cors.rb

require 'rack/cors'

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins 'http://localhost:3000'
      resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :patch, :put], credentials: true
    end
end
```