# mootools Request class and CORS

Tags: xmlhttprequest, mootools, cors

I'm trying to use CORS to have a script do an Ajax request to geonames. 
My script calls this web service method: http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#findNearby

If you check the response headers of the sample call, they include:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

When I try this with mootools (version 1.4.5 just downloaded):

```
var urlGeonames = "http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName";
var req = new Request({
  method: 'get',
  url: urlGeonames,
  data: {
'lat': '89.18',
'lng': '-0.37',
'username': 'myusername',
'radius': '5'
  }
}).send();
```

then I get an error that says :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load
http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName?lat=89.18&lng=-0.37&username=myusername&radius=5. 
Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.</pre>
```

On the other hand, when I try old style Ajax code like this:

```
invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
if(invocation)
 {    
  invocation.open('GET', urlFlickr, true);
  invocation.onreadystatechange = handler;
  invocation.send(); 
 }
```

then it works and I get the XML response in the XHR responseXML.

I found this post [A CORS POST request works from plain javascript, but why not with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584923/a-cors-post-request-works-from-plain-javascript-but-why-not-with-jquery) that is similar. But here I'm not dealing with my server so I can only work on the javascript side.

Has anyone worked with CORS and mootools and can help on this issue ?
Thanks so much
    JM

Comment: BTW This site and API is AWESOME!!! I just discovered it a few months ago. Let me know if you need additional help with the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer on this other thread:
[MooTools CORS request vs native Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445337/mootools-cors-request-vs-native-javascript)

Might help.

Basically, the X-Requested-With header is automatically sent by the Mootools with the request, but the server either has to be configured to accept that header or you can remove it using

```
delete foo.headers['X-Requested-With'];
```

Before calling

```
foo.send();
```

To allow it by the server, you can add this to the .htaccess file of your script that gives back the JSON data:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

So yours would look like:

```
var myJSON = new Request({
    url: 'http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON',
    data: {
       'lat': '89.18',
       'lng': '-0.37',
       'username': 'myusername'
    },
    onRequest: function(url){
        // a script tag is created with a src attribute equal to url
    },
    onComplete: function(data){
       // the request was completed.
       console.log(data);
    }
});
delete myJSON.headers['X-Requested-With'];
myJSON.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey man check out mootools more JSONP this will solve your problem:

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Request/Request.JSONP

Also it looks like your forgetting to ask for it in JSON format from geonames.org

Try something like:

```
var myJSONP = new Request.JSONP({
    url: 'http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON',
    data: {
       'lat': '89.18',
       'lng': '-0.37',
       'username': 'myusername'
    },
    onRequest: function(url){
        // a script tag is created with a src attribute equal to url
    },
    onComplete: function(data){
       // the request was completed.
       console.log(data);
    }
}).send();
```

Hope this helps!