# MooTools CORS request vs native Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, request, cross-domain, mootools

I have this MooTools code:

```
new Request.JSON({
  method: 'POST',
  url: URL, /*URL TO ANOTHER DOMAIN*/
  onSuccess: function(r){
    callback(r);
  }
}).post(data);
```

And this code doesn't send POST requests (OPTIONS only)...
Look at the code below (it works great):

```
var http = null,
  params = Object.toQueryString(data);
try {
  http = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e) {
  try {
    http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      http = null;
      alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
    }
  }
}
var url = URL;
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(http.responseText); /*OR EVAL*/
    callback(jsonData);
  }
};
http.open("POST", url);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.send(params);
```

**EDIT**:

Tried: `.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`
Still nothing... Where can there be a problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If it sends an OPTIONS request, that sounds like a [CORS preflight request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest), which suggests you are using a non-simple request header in your cross-site request. Your non-Mootools code sets `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but your Mootools code might not.

Comment: Try setting the option `headers` in your mootools request.

Comment: Tried: .setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); Still nothing...where is a problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because MooTools bundles some extra stuff with the request headers.

eg. if your htaccess says:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

you need to craft your request like that:

```
var foo = new Request({
    url: 'http://fragged.org/Epitome/example/data/',
    method: 'get',
    onComplete: function (data) {
        // returns an object with name and surname  
        new Element('div[html="{name} {surname}"]'.substitute(JSON.decode(data))).inject(document.body);
    }
});

// need to remove that or CORS will need to match it specifically
delete foo.headers['X-Requested-With'];
foo.send();
```

This is why you are only seeing the OPTIONS pre-flight. It does not like you :)

You could change the `.htaccess` to also match `X-Requested-With`, which is probably some extra "security".

See http://jsfiddle.net/7zUSu/1/ for a working example - I did that a while ago when I wanted to get this change to Request https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2381 fixed.

Comment: Great answer as usual! Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you; this has most probably saved me some hours of hair pulling.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by (OPTIONS only)? Both examples sends POST request, only difference is in Accept request headers.

MooTools sends `Accept: application/json`, while native sends `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`.

This may affect how the server responds.