# How to make Request.JSON work cross-domain (Mootools)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

I am executing an `index.html` file from the server test1.com. Mootools library file is included in this `index.html` file.

Following is a script that calls a PHP page:

```
<script>
  var request = new Request.JSON({
    url: 'http://test1.com/ajaxtest.php',
    onSuccess: function(data) {
      // the request was completed.
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  }).send();
</script>
```

### ajaxtest.php

```
<?php
  $arr['age'] = 30;
  $arr['place'] = 'London';
  echo json_encode($arr); exit;
?>
```

While executing `index.html`, I'm getting the correct output"

> {"age":30,"place":"London"}

Now, `ajaxtest.php` is residing on another server, say test2.com. How to change the above script to make it work as earlier?

Comment: Are you looking for [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)? Why doesn't it work as earlier when residing on `test2.com`, what errors are you getting (set up an error handler!)?

Comment: Is he other server set up to handle CORS?

Comment: @epascarello. I have added the code

 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
in ajaxtest.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript | Mootools vs native javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445337/javascript-mootools-vs-native-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will be helpful to you now.

You need to use the Request.JSONP Class object to make cross site request:

```
new Request.JSONP({
url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json",
data: {
    q: "Arsenal"
},
onComplete: function(tweets) {
    // Log the result to console for inspection
    console.info("Twitter returned: ",tweets);
}
}).send();
```