# nginx, jquery - getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin error while doing a POST

Tags: jquery, json, post, nginx

This is the error I see in my chrome console.

XMLHttpRequest can not load {URL}. Origin {URL} is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I've tried to configure my NGINX for CORS:

```
location / {
    if ($http_origin) {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS";
    }
```

But that doesn't seem to help.

The jquery call looks like this:

```
var submissionData = '{"tweet_id":"'+tweet_id+'", "question_id":"'+question_id+'", '+choiceString+', "extra_passback":"'+extra_passback+'"}';
$.post("http://ec2[...].amazonaws.com/question/answer/", submissionData, function(data) {console.log("success");});
```

I'm not even sure if the problem is with jquery or nginx.

Comment: you must be look at [link](http://bionicspirit.com/blog/2011/03/24/cross-domain-requests.html), ah do you have crossdomain.xml in your root dir?

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584923/a-cors-post-request-works-from-plain-javascript-but-why-not-with-jquery), I added two more headers (in addition to the two you have mentioned in your question above) and it works for me, with JQuery json cross-domain request:

```
add_header         Access-Control-Allow-Headers   Content-Type;
add_header         Access-Control-Max-Age         86400;
```