# Enabling cross origin request

Tags: html, ajax, cors

This is my code. I'm connecting to the server on localhost 8080 from the localhost and I get the error because its not the same origin. I looked at a lot of links which were useful but I don't know how to combine them with this code. Here are a few of the links I referred.

[CORS - Cross-Domain AJAX Without JSONP By Allowing Origin On Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318426/cors-cross-domain-ajax-without-jsonp-by-allowing-origin-on-server)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 

<form action="http://localhost:8080/newjersey/rest/hello" name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" method="GET">
ID:<br>
<input type="text" name="ID">
<br>
Notes:<br>
<input type="text" name="notes">
<br><br>
Ignore:<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="ignore[]" value="1">Avg
<input type="checkbox" name="ignore[]" value="2">Time

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<script>
//callback handler for form submit

$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{
    //$(this).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    //alert("Its here");
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    //var formURL = "http://localhost:8080/newjersey/rest/hello/";
    //alert(formURL);
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "GET",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            //data: return data from server
            //alert("Success " + textStatus);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            //if fails      
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    $(this).unbind(e); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});

$("#ajaxform").submit(); //Submit  the FORM
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried allowing foreign origins on the SERVER?

Add this on the server side! (where apache/nginx runs)

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

example in apache2 or htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I'm using https://chiaboy.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/simple-jersey-example-with-intellij-idea-and-tomcat/

Comment: check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383109/access-control-allow-origin-in-tomcat

Comment: I think that should help! Thanks!