# Strange $.post() AJAX error when parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, post

I am facing this strange error in using `$.post`.

**works**

```
$("#add-video").click(function(){
    var url = $("#new-video-url").val();
    $('#loader').show();
    $.post( base_url + "forms/coach/get_url.php", { url:url, base_url:base_url }, function(data){
        alert(data);
                    $('#loader').hide();        
    });
});
```

The above piece of code, shows me the json array I am receiving using a php file, and also shows the `title` field here, and hides the loader image.

But when I `alert(data.title)`, it shows me undefined. More over, when I add datatype 'json' to `$.post`,

**doesn't work**

```
$("#add-video").click(function(){
    var url = $("#new-video-url").val();
    $('#loader').show();
    $.post( base_url + "forms/coach/get_url.php", { url:url, base_url:base_url }, function(data){
        alert(data);
                    $('#loader').hide();        
    }, "json"); //Added datatype here.
});
```

This neither alerts anything nor does it hide the loader image. I also tried,

```
$("#add-video").click(function(){
    var url = $("#new-video-url").val();
    $('#loader').show();
    $.post( base_url + "forms/coach/get_url.php", { url:url, base_url:base_url }, function(data){
        jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    alert(data.title);
                    $('#loader').hide();        
    });
});
```

The above one too neither alerts anything nor does it hide the loader. And then I tried this one too that did nothing.

```
$("#add-video").click(function(){
    var url = $("#new-video-url").val();
    $('#loader').show();
    $.post( base_url + "forms/coach/get_url.php", { url:url, base_url:base_url }, function(data){
        jQuery.parseJSON(data);  //tried without this too.
                    alert(data['title']);
                    $('#loader').hide();        
    });
});
```

The strangest thing is that I have previously used json as I have shown in the 2nd script(out of 4), and that works normally. My JS console too doesn't show any errors or warning. What am I doing wrong here? How do I access the title field of data?

If this helps, here is how I send the json array,

```
$json = array("title" => $title, "embed" => $embed, "desc" => $desc, "duration" => $duration, "date" => $date);
print_r(json_encode($json));
```

I would really appreciate if someone can point out the error and tell me why my scripts are failing, similar functions worked in other js file.

here is my data, that is returned by server,

> {"title":"Sunn Raha Hai Na Tu Aashiqui 2 Full Song With Lyrics |
>   Aditya Roy Kapur, Shraddha Kapoor","embed":"\r\t\t\t\t\t\r\t\t\t\t\t</param></param>\r\t\t\t\t\t</param>\r\t\t\t\t\t\r\t\t\t\t\t</embed></object>","desc":"Presenting
>   full song \"Sun Raha Hai Na Tu\" with lyrics from movie \"Aashiqui 2\"
>   produced by T-Series Films & Vishesh Films, starring Aditya Roy Kapur,
>   Shraddha Kapoor in voice of Ankit Tiwari. \n\nSong: SUNN RAHA
>   HAI\nSinger: ANKIT TIWARI\nMusic Director: ANKIT TIWARI\nAssistant Mix
>   Engineer - MICHAEL EDWIN PILLAI\nMixed and Mastered by ERIC PILLAI
>   (FUTURE SOUND OF BOMBAY)\nLyrics:SANDEEP NATH\nMovie: AASHIQUI
>   2\nProducer: BHUSHAN KUMAR KRISHAN KUAMR  Producer: MUKESH BHATT
>   \nDirector: MOHIT SURI\nMusic Label: T-SERIES\n\nBuy from iTunes -
>   https://itunes.apple.com/in/album/aashiqui-2-original-motion/id630590910?ls=1\n\nEnjoy
>   & stay connected with us!! \n\nSUBSCRIBE T-Series channel for
>   unlimited entertainment\nhttp://www.youtube.com/tseries\n\nCircle
>   us on G+ \nhttp://www.google.com/+tseriesmusic\n\nLike us on
>   Facebook\nhttp://www.facebook.com/tseriesmusic\n\nFollow
>   us\nhttp://www.twitter.com/_Tseries","duration":"391","date":"2013-04-03"}

**Edit**

This worked suddenly.. :o

```
  $("#add-video").click(function(){
    var url = $("#new-video-url").val();
    $('#loader').show();
    $.post( base_url + "forms/coach/get_url.php", { url:url, base_url:base_url }, function(data){
            alert(data.desc);
            console.log(data.desc);
            $("#loader").hide();

    }, "json");
});
```

Comment: And what shows `console.log(data)` exactly?

Comment: `jQuery.parseJSON(data);` doesn't modify `data` in place. You'd have to use `data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`. That shouldn't matter, because setting the `dataType` as "json" should automatically parse it (do what you're doing already). Also, instead of using the callback of `$.post()`, just take advantage of the methods `.done()`, `.fail()` on the result of `$.post()`. For example: `$.post("url", {}).done(function (data) { }).fail(function (_, textStatus, errorThrown) { };`

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an error in the parsing, because your code works when you **don't** have the response parsed (meaning it's parsed as text, which has `data` being a string). That means the success callback won't execute, and instead an error callback will, which you can look at with my previous comment

Comment: I have a feeling it's because you're using `print_r` and not `echo`. Try changing that. And also set the `dataType` parameter for `$.post`, otherwise `data` will be a string

Comment: @u_mulder same thing as i told with alert. It logs data when I don't use json word or data.title anywhere. But doesn't when I use the last 3 methods in the question.

Comment: can you post your json contents?

Comment: @Ian That didn't work, and I used print_r in the previous script too that's working and is similar to the 2nd script(out of 4 here).

Comment: @MoazzamKhan Okay i will in a while.

Comment: @OptimusPrime Ahh okay, I thought maybe there would be extra whitespace or something that would throw off the parser. Either way, you **need** to use the `.fail()` method, because that's clearly what's being called (not the success `.done()` method) and you can find out more and debug from there

Comment: @Ian yes the problem is while parsing the data. Or it works well. I will add the data contents, may be that may help.

Comment: give me the get_url.php code. I want to know what parameter you have sendint to your ajax page

Comment: @Ian I have added the contents of data. Now am trying using .done() and .fail().

Comment: @ChinmaySahu I have just now added the data returned. I hope now php file is not needed.

Comment: Go to http://jsonlint.com  and copy/paste your JSON; I get an error on validation, which means the parser won't work. It looks like some text inside of the `desc` value, because if I remove that text, it validates fine

Comment: Actually, that "error" is talking about the line break in the middle of the `desc` (right before `\nDirector:`), which I'm not sure why is there. It should be a `\n` like the others.

Comment: @Ian Yes I notice that too. But I am using youtube api's to get these info. What can I do to make desc valid. Or so that json can parse it.

Comment: @Ian Now something stranger happened, the code I just appended to question, worked :o Now why? for the same video, for same desc, it works.

Comment: Two things - are you sure you aren't `echo`ing, or `print_r`ing anything else in your PHP script? Although it seems straightforward, you might want to post that code. Also, what happens if you **don't** include the `desc` key/value in the encoded array? Does the error still occur?

Comment: Yes, these is the only thing I am echoing. I have one if else. Other things I echo are in if condition, this is in else condition. @Ian

Comment: @OptimusPrime Okay, and what about my other question? If you don't include the `desc` key/value?

Comment: I think the problem was with single `\ `, when the string is getting parsed it should have `\\ ` double slashes

Comment: And I am using youtube api's, so if youtube can send me the data as json array, why can't i use it as json array?

Comment: You might read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call to get a greater appreciation of ajax.

Answer (score 0):

In comments, you mention that this AJAX corresponds to a YouTube API.

[YouTube's blog](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/05/unlocking-javascripts-potential-with.html) announced in 2012 that they would support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), which uses server-side header flags that compatible browsers interpret as permitting requests that would otherwise be prohibited by browser security [Same-Origin-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Assuming, as you say, the first example worked, the first issue was "Why did (a subsequent) `alert(data.title)` fail? (my edit) ".  If you type `alert(data.title)` in the console, it will fail because the `scope` of `data` is the callback function where it is defined as a parameter, and in the global scope `data` is undefined.  If you try to pass `data` back to the `global scope` somehow, it can still be undefined because `$.post` returns immediately, before the data has been fetched, and merely queues a request and sets the callback function you supply to handle the reply.

The second example, which explicitly sets the [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) `dataType` parameter to `'json'`,  may fail with `CORS` based API because the [mime types for json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type) are not allowed to be sent up to the server as `Content-Type:` for a `simple CORS request`, and `$.post` will as far as I know only do simple requests without preflight. `$.ajax` can possibly do the more complex requests if correctly applied.

The work around to keep using `$.post` is not to use `json` as the expected data type, send requests up as form data, the server may send you back json anyway if that is what the API says will happen, which can be verified while testing the code.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

> Simple requests
>
> A simple cross-site request is one that:
>
> Only uses GET, HEAD or POST.
>
> If POST is used to send data to the
>   server, the Content-Type of the data sent to the server with the HTTP
>   POST request is one of application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
>   multipart/form-data, or text/plain.

Notice that `application/json` did not make the list of what `Content-Type` is permissible in a `simple CORS request`.

See also [A CORS POST request works from plain javascript, but why not with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584923/a-cors-post-request-works-from-plain-javascript-but-why-not-with-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

Use ajax as

```
$.ajax({
url:url,
type:'post',
dataType:'json',
success:callback
})
```

With this type you can set lots of parameter in low level.
With datatype attribute jQuery parses `JSON` and send data as callback function.

Comment: That's fine. But what's the problem here? I have used $.post at other places too. It works there.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to replace all single `\` with double '\' to feed it to `JSON.parse`.