# What is the difference between $.ajax with type: post and $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Consider this code:

```
$.ajax({
           url: "http://x.com/api/AnnouncementCategory/Save",
           type: "Post",
           success: function (data) {
               //Grab our data from Ground Control
               alert(data);
           },
           error: function (event) {
               //If any errors occurred - detail them here
               alert("Transmission failed. (An error has occurred)");
           }
       });
```

With above code we can post data cross domain an everything is ok. But when i use this code:

```
$.post(' http://x.com/AnnouncementCategory/Save')
```

I get this error:

> OPTIONS http://x.com/AnnouncementCategory/Save Request
>   header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers. jquery-1.9.1.js:8526 XMLHttpRequest
>   cannot load http://x.com/AnnouncementCategory/Save. Request
>   header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

I see the jquery source code:

```
function ( url, data, callback, type ) {
        // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
        if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
            type = type || callback;
            callback = data;
            data = undefined;
        }

        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            dataType: type,
            data: data,
            success: callback
        });
    }
```

Jquery also use ajax in post.
**I know what is my error and just want to know:**What is the difference between $.ajax with type: post  and jquery post?

Comment: might be nothing, but is that an extra space in the `$.post`?  Just before the `http`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `$.ajax` method always **sends the "x-requested-with" header** for any cross domain requests, unlike the `$.post`. The error you are getting is because of the way external server is handling the external request. Please [look here](http://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working/) to get more info how the CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing – i.e. cross domain Ajax) is being handled. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5671316/2609826) you will find the similar problem and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to the question you have asked is, a shorthand version of `$.ajax`, as described in the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

The docs do state that:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

The question that you didn't ask, but perhaps is what you would really like to ask, is *"why does cross-domain request work for me using $.ajax with a simple POST type, but not with $.post?"*. For that you would probably need to provide a bit more information.