# return value fails when call java restful webservice from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, rest

I have a restful webservice which written in java. And I call it in javascript.

When I call webservice, all codes works perfectly but don't return value perfectly. My codes are here:

**ws:**

```
@RestController
public class VillageService {

    @Autowired

private InnerService innerService;


@RequestMapping(value = "/services/getVillages")
public  Village getAllVillages(@RequestParam int param) throws JSONException {

      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Village result = innerService.getAllVillagesCacheable(param);
      long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
      System.out.println("süre: " + elapsedTime);         

      startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Village result2 = innerService.getAllVillages(param);
      stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
      System.out.println("süre cache'siz: " + elapsedTime);       

      return result;
    }
}
```

**Js:**

```
        function callWS()
        {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost/services/getVillages/',
            data: "param=5", // the data in form-encoded format, ie as it would appear on a querystring
            dataType: "json", // the data type we want back, so text.  The data will come wrapped in xml
            success: function (data) {
                alert("party hard"); // show the string that was returned, this will be the data inside the xml wrapper
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("restful cagirmada hata"); // show the string that was returned, this will be the data inside the xml wrapper
            }
        });


        };
```

When I call ws, all "prinln" codes works perfectly but not return value. My js not finish with "success" it fall into "error:" case.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do a `System.out.println` for `result` and check browser console for any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the data using AJAX call as:

```
data: {param:5},
```

Use HTTP Request to read the param and you also need to have `@ResponseBody` annotation for a method that returns JSON:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/services/getVillages")
@ResponseBody
public  Village getAllVillages(HttpServletRequest request) throws JSONException {
      String param = request.getParameter("param");
```

Comment: Do a `System.out.println` for result and check browser console for any errors.

Comment: I am getting .. required Cross Origin Resource sharing (CORS) error

Comment: Good, that is something you can google: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Try the suggested solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584923/a-cors-post-request-works-from-plain-javascript-but-why-not-with-jquery

Comment: thx for replying. I found the solution at http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests

Comment: How can I pass an object instead of param=5 ?