# Send Text Message Through Javascript to External Service

Tags: javascript

Since Javascript doesn't support external (cross-domain) HttpRequest, is it still possible to send text message to external service using Javascript ?

**In the case, the external service is not in our control. So, it's not possible to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*" in the remote site.**

By the way, to add a php in the local site is not the option, too.

Comment: Of course javascript support cross-domain http requests. Please read more about CORS and Same Origin Policy.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: We can't controll the server side to add (access-control...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584923/a-cors-post-request-works-from-plain-javascript-but-why-not-with-jquery

Answer (score -1):

you should set server http response header first.It's no business with your front-end javascript code

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

or

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:your domain
```

Code is like

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
```

Comment: The external service is out-of-our-control, so we can't add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*"

Comment: @CrayKao: Only now, you said cross origin is not in your control. So, it is not correct to down-vote this answer

Comment: @CrayKao: Check if this would help <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310112/why-am-i-seeing-an-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-error>

Comment: Thanks, and need to find another way to send the message.