# JSON data parsing using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-ajaxq

I am new to JSON. I have data.json, jQuery.min.js and try.html files within a folder. The problem is that it doesn't show any output on the screen. I also tried some of the examples from other websites as well as StackOverflow too, but the problem remains the same. Please help me out.

try.html :

```
<body>
<div id="append-here"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on('ready', function(){
       $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) { 
          $.each(data, function(index, element) {
             $('#append-here').append(element.name);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

data.json :

```
[ 
  { "id" : "1", "name" : "test1" },
  { "id" : "2", "name" : "test2" },
  { "id" : "3", "name" : "test3" },
  { "id" : "4", "name" : "test4" },
  { "id" : "5", "name" : "test5" }
```

]

And this is what I get on JS console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/avi/Desktop/html/jsAjax/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Comment: Mention the proper path of your file. Looks like you're accessing the file which is not on your server.

Comment: the error isn't thrown on the JSON file, you just can't access the file without the permissions from the browser you're using (chrome I think)... this is what `Cross origin request` means.

Comment: It looks like you open html file in browser and try to make ajax request. You need to set up virtual host

Comment: Try fully-pathing the `data.json` in your `$.getJSON()`, that might fix the CORS error.

Comment: You cannot use AJAX to get something that's on your local filesystem.

Comment: Actually, I just did it in simple Html and javaScript without localhost. Do I have to run it in local host ?

Comment: Firefox allows you to make ajax request on the file system, but you should really set up a dev server.

Comment: Thank you guys ... I wasted whole day, figuring out what's wrong until I asked here and finally found out that I need to run it in a localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running into a CORS problem: http://enable-cors.org/

See this for more info: [A CORS POST request works from plain javascript, but why not with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584923/a-cors-post-request-works-from-plain-javascript-but-why-not-with-jquery)