# UserProfile REST API using jquery is not working in google chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, office365-restapi

User profiles REST API call is not working in google chrome

following code:-

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager
    /getpropertiesfor(@v)?@v='i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cuser%40domain.onmicrosoft.com'",
  type: "GET",
  headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: error was not handled in code,its mistake,but same code was working fine in IE browser

Comment: I am getting error of forbidden access(status code 403) in chrome but working in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `cache: false` to ajax options. and their is one extra `'` in your url.

Try this please. let me know if it helps

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager
    /getpropertiesfor(@v)?@v='i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cuser%40domain.onmicrosoft.com",
  type: "GET",
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

---

### UPDATED

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses) as it will give an idea for why you are getting `403 Forbidden status code`

For summary:

> The 403 Forbidden response. It’s
>   permanent, it’s tied to my application logic, and it’s a more concrete
>   response than a 401.
>
> Receiving a 403 response is the server telling
>   you, “I’m sorry. I know who you are–I believe who you say you are–but
>   you just don’t have permission to access this resource. Maybe if you
>   ask the system administrator nicely, you’ll get permission. But please
>   don’t bother me again until your predicament changes.”

In your case it might be

You are not authorized to perform the requested operation on the given resource.

---

**Cross Origion AJAX**

```
    var accesstoken = localStorage.getItem('myApiSession');

    var authHeaders = {};
    if (accesstoken) {
        authHeaders.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accesstoken;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:13838' + link,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        headers: authHeaders,
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
```

In webApi

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class SearchController : ApiController
{
    public object Get(string str)
    {

        WebServiceBLL WebBLL = new WebServiceBLL(new NaqshaMaker2Entities());
        var stre = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(WebBLL.Search(str));

        return Json(new { result = stre }); 

    }

}
```

This is a correct way on both sides to make a successfull cross origin request

Comment: I am getting error of forbidden access(status code 403) in chrome but working in IE.cache: false, didn't work

Comment: If you are having an `forbidden access` error. It means your `headers` are not correct. Are you using an api ?

Comment: what should be content of header.

Comment: I cannot see your console log error. I think you missed them. Please type again. Thank you

Comment: error after passing authentication :----XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://<site URL>/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:14361' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: you said after adding header your forbidden access was gone and you where recieving some other error. Can you tell me please what where those ?

Comment: i added    xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },                  for authentication

Comment: You webapi is refusing the request as i told. In order to resolve it you must either add cross origion access to your webapi

Comment: new error was    XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://<site URL>/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'localhost:14361'; is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute

Comment: any helpful link to implement cross origion access to webapi

Comment: withCredentials: false was again causing forbidden error

Comment: In above example I have shown how can you implement a cross origin request. It is from a working project. Now one thing to not is `accesstoken` you need it in order to make it valid call. Else it will fail. Moreover you have to add `dataType: "json"`

Comment: I will give you link to implement cross origin request

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584923/a-cors-post-request-works-from-plain-javascript-but-why-not-with-jquery

Comment: WebApi should be added in my code? by using above 2 code,hopefully I would find my solution