# Unable to send POST request to Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, http, google-apps-script, xmlhttprequest

I have a Google Apps Script that is supposed to receive and process base64-encoded data. Sending CORS GET requests to it works well, but the data strings are too long to be sent as GET parameters, so I have to send it in CORS POST requests. Unfortunately, all POST requests to the script gets HTTP 405 and does not include the `access-control-allow-origin:*`-header.

This is an excerpt of my current server side script:

```
function doGet(e) {
   // Irrelevant because GET requests works fine
}

function doPost(e) {
  // Doesn't work:

  Logger.log(e);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("It works!");
}
```

I am using angularJS on the client side to send the requests, here is a screenshot from Chrome of a request:
[image]

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: How are you issuing a post request? Could you share example header that gives an error? Also, Logger.log(e) doesn't log for web apps.

Comment: I added an example request to the answer now @JackBrown

Comment: Perhaps, similar to [issue here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584923/a-cors-post-request-works-from-plain-javascript-but-why-not-with-jquery).

Comment: @JackBrown Thank you for the link, it helped me solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it got solved when I added the header `Content-Type: undefined` to the request.