# Jquery Ajax jsonp invalid token error for invalid json but it appears correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Im currently trying to use the OSRS api in jquery.

I have used it prior to this with httparty in rails but wanted to see if i could do it in a javascript way.

However i seem to be having a problem parsing the contence of the response despite it appearing valid.

My code can be seen below:

```
// jquery Stuff
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var url_test = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=207&format=json";
  $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: url_test ,
    }).done(function ( data ) {
      console.log(data);
      alert( "Load was performed." );
  });

});
```

This is the 'broken' responce i get from the api which throws the error of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```
{"item":{"icon":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/1492081307848_obj_sprite.gif?id=207","icon_large":"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/1492081307848_obj_big.gif?id=207","id":207,"type":"Default","typeIcon":"http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Default","name":"Grimy ranarr weed","description":"It needs cleaning.","current":{"trend":"neutral","price":"7,338"},"today":{"trend":"negative","price":"- 20"},"members":"true","day30":{"trend":"positive","change":"+2.0%"},"day90":{"trend":"positive","change":"+8.0%"},"day180":{"trend":"positive","change":"+8.0%"}}}
```

Is there someway that i can load this data correctly. I think its because of using jsonp if i where to guess. However i cant seem to load the api threw json data type as it throws a CORS error. So im a little stuck and any help with this would be great thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What you're returning is `JSON`, not `JSONP`. Your response looks like

```
{"name" : "Joe"}   //json format
```

and `jQuery` is expecting something like this:

```
jQuery42534534636363({"name" : "Joe"})   //jsonp format
```

If you actually need to use `JSONP` to get around the same origin policy, then the server serving needs to be able to actually return a JSONP response.

If the same origin policy isn't an issue for your application, then you just need to fix the `dataType` in your `jQuery.ajax` call to be `json` instead of `jsonp`.

```
// jquery Stuff
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var url_test = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=207&format=json";
  $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    url: url_test ,
    }).done(function ( data ) {
      console.log(data);
      alert( "Load was performed." );
  });

});
```

[JSONP](http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=processJSON&tags=monkey&tagmode=any&format=json) Example (a wrapping function)

[JSON Example](https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/flight/AA/100/departing/2013/10/4?appId=19d57e69&appKey=e0ea60854c1205af43fd7b1203005d59&callback=)

Comment: Is there any way to work around it because i dont own the server its not my endpoint and httparty in rails seemed to work for some reason. (formatting was messed up) but i can handle string manipulation. Any way i can get the responce and not parse it automatically.

Comment: You can simple add one plugin (allow-cross-origin) or you can try this tutorials from [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584923/a-cors-post-request-works-from-plain-javascript-but-why-not-with-jquery)